# Embedding Stan in C++ application

Tags: c++, mcmc, rinside, stan

I wanted to know whether it is possible to incorporate Stan in another C++ application. Since Stan is also written in C++, there should be a way. Currently, I am using RInside to achieve this but then you have all this data transferring which is time-consuming.

Comment: You will probably get a better response on the Stan user google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/stan-users

Comment: thanks. I will post it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What specifically did you want from Stan?  We're going to separate out the math library into a standalone include for Stan 2.7 --- that contains all the matrix, probability, and autodiff code.  Our repos already reflect this structure.  All of the MCMC and transform and I/O code is callable through C++, as is the translator from a Stan program to a C++ class.

Comment: Are there any news concerning the possibility to incorporate Stan into C/C++? Thanks!

Comment: I responded via the question to our users list.  We monitor stackoverflow for Stan tags and also our list, but don't want everyone to double our work by cross-posting questions.